# Using SQL in PHP works to insert to database but not pull from database

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to count the number of rows in a database and display it.

I've seen others using

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_NAME
```

I've tried it, and it always returns `1`.

I can insert into the database using the same program, but I cannot pull correctly for some reason.

```
$itemIDQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM item";

$itemIDResults = $conn->query($itemIDQuery);
if (!$itemIDResults)
{
     die($conn->error);
}
else
{
     echo "ITEM ID QUERIED SUCCESSFULLY.<br><br>";
}
```

It's echoing how it's supposed to, but the value of what is brought back is still 1 even if there are 5 items in the database. Any ideas?

Comment: `$itemIDResults` is just a flag to say the `query()` method executed properly, you need to actually fetch the data.

Comment: use if($itemIDResults->num_rows)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this to fetch one record which will contain count

```
$temp = $conn->query("select count(*) FROM TABLE_NAME");
$countArr = $temp->fetch_row();
echo $countArr[0];
```

[mysqli_result::fetch_row](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php) -- mysqli_fetch_row — Get a result row as an enumerated array.

You can see link documentation for example usage.